# Is an irreducible affine variety isomorphic to some affine hypersurface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, affine-varieties, birational-geometry

I'm reading the basics of birational geometry in Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry, 1" third edition. In theorem 1.8 he proves that

> Every irreducible affine variety $X\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ is
> birationally equivalent to some hypersurface $Y\subseteq \mathbb{A}^m$
> for some $m$. ([In fact, $m=n+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419588/every-n-dimensional-variety-is-birationally-equivalent-to-a-hypersurface-in))

I'm wondering whether the same statement still holds true or not if we replace "birationally equivalent" with "isomorphic". So, my question is:

> Is every irreducible affine variety $X\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$
> isomorphic to some affine hypersurface $Y\subseteq \mathbb{A}^m$ for some
> $m$?

I don't think this is true (it seems "too good to be true"), but I don't know how can I disprove such statement.
Can you provide me with an example of an affine variety which is never isomorphic to an affine hypersurface? (I can work out the details myself, I just can't think of an elementary way or example to do this).
I'd be surprised if the statement is true, if so, how could I prove it? (it should be an important result in such case)

Related question: [Any quasi-affine variety is isomorphic to a closed subvariety in $\mathbb{A}^n\setminus \mathbb{A}^m$ for some $m,n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491215/any-quasi-affine-variety-is-isomorphic-to-a-closed-subvariety-in-mathbban-s)

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not true, because for a hypersurface $Y \subset \mathbb{A}^m$ one has
$$
\dim T_y(Y) \le m = \dim(Y) + 1,
$$
which is not always true for an affine variety.

Comment: Thanks, I am a differential geometer by training, I'm just learning the basics of classical algebraic geometry by myself. I haven't read much about dimension or algebraic tangent spaces yet but I can follow your argument. These results all remind me of Whitney's embedding theorem or Chow's lemma in complex geometry

Comment: What if X is smooth?